# AppInstance.RedirectActivationTo() fails with "The group or resource is not in the correct state to perform the requested operation." error

Tags: c#, uwp

I am trying to determine which instance of my multi-instance UWP application should be activated based on the argument passed to it:

```
var instances = AppInstance.GetInstances();
            if (instances.Count() != 0)
            {
                instances[0].RedirectActivationTo();
            }
```

I have tried placing the code in app.xaml.cs (OnActivated) and main.xaml.cs (OnNavigatedTo) and they both throw the "The group or resource is not in the correct state to perform the requested operation." error for which there appears to be no documentation.

How can I redirect the activation to a current instance?

Answer (score 1):

The [AppInstance class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.appinstance?view=winrt-22621) should be used in a main method. This is mentioned in the document: **The AppInstance class is intended to be used in the Main method of the app. If this class is used later, the property values may be null, and the methods may fail.**

To create a main method of UWP app, you will need to disable the defaulted main method which is generated automatically first. Please right click on your project and choose `properties`, in the `Build` tab, add **DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_MAIN** to the Conditional Compilation Symbols.

Then you could add a new static class to your project and add a new static `main` mehtod in the class.

I found a blog which have detailed steps about how to use `AppInstance.RedirectActivationTo` method, you could take a look at: [Multiple instances support for UWP apps (Part 2): Redirection](https://blog.pieeatingninjas.be/2018/02/25/multiple-instances-support-for-uwp-apps-part-2-redirection/)

Besides if you want to redirect to an existing instance, it will be better to register the instance first.